# compressing a character huffman tree

Tags: java, recursion, huffman-code

I try to compress just one character in huffman tree. If the data is the searched one, return. If not go traversing left or right. For example: I hope to get `1010` for `a` or `00001` for `u`(a and u is kind of symbol). But I get `11111`. How can be the issue fixed?

```
public void compress(char a, BinaryTree huffTree, StringBuilder result) {

            if (huffTree.root.data.equals(a)) {
                return;
            }

            //else if (!huffTree.getLeftSubtree().isLeaf())

            else if (huffTree.getLeftSubtree() != null) {
                result.append("1");
                compress(a, huffTree.getLeftSubtree(), result);

            }
            else if (huffTree.getRightSubtree() != null) {
                result.append("0");
                compress(a, huffTree.getRightSubtree(), result);

            }
        }
```